# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hangs on Waiting for table metadata lock

Tags: mysql, locking, mysql-5.7, metadata, hang

I'm using a dockerized MySQL 5.7.13 as part of an integration test of an application. The way the system works is as follows:

1. I start up the main application. It opens up a connection to MySQL, but does not perform any queries.
2. I start the integration test setup and drop the old table if it was left behind by the previous run:

   `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS unit_device`
3. I then go on and create the table like this:

   `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unit_device (
       id CHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
       unit_id CHAR(36), 
       device_id CHAR(36), 
       deleted_at DATETIME, 
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
   )`
4. I then insert some values into the table and trigger work in the main application which makes one SELECT:

   `SELECT unit_id, device_id FROM unit_device WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`
5. Then I drop the table:

   `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS unit_device`

However, when I try to run this query, it hangs seemingly forever for some reason. If I close the connection from the main application, the query resumes. One thing that seems suspicious is that once the main application has made its select once, I can see the following information in the output of `show engine innodb status`: `1 read views open inside InnoDB`

I must be doing something seriously wrong here, but after hours of research I was still unable to figure out what's causing the hang, or whether the problem is in the test or the main application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I was using the `aiomysql` library for Python and it turns out that it somehow bypasses the autocommit setting in the database and requires commits by default. However, this somehow applies to `SELECT` statements as well, but does not work even when called explicitly. I fixed it by adding `autocommit=True` to the code which creates the pool, as suggested by [this note in Github](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql/issues/329).